# Biztalk string concatenate in mapping of nested looping record to one element of dest node

Tags: mapping, biztalk

have some requirement where I  want to do comulation of Referance number in below map and send it to destination  SELNO (marked In orange below), 
where 431 (marked below ) is repeating record , when I directly use cumulative functoid its concatenating all the reference numbers in entire file , however I want it should as per 304( Jobs_304_Root) Group iteration .

[image]

304000000000280645000000000147424000000000000001TAEU1234563
416000000000280645000000000281853000000000000001QUANTITY  416000000000280645000000000281853000000000000002QUANTITY
426000000000280645000000002117336000000000000001UNITMARKS MARKS
431000000000280645000000002117336000000000000001UNIT      SEALNUMBERTAEUSEAL1234                                                SP2                                                                             000000000000000
431000000000280645000000002117336000000000000002UNIT      SEALNUMBERTAEUSEAL2                                                   SP1                                                                             000000000000000
431000000000280645000000002117336000000000000003UNIT      SEALNUMBERTAEUSEAL3                                                   SP3                                                                             000000000000000
427000000000280645000000001117420000000000000001UNITITEM  ITEMNO                                   000000000000000000001000000000000000003970033
304000000000280645000000000147424000000000000002MAEU1234567         416000000000280645000000000281855000000000000001QUANTITY  JOBUNITS
416000000000280645000000000281855000000000000002QUANTITY  JOBUNITS
426000000000280645000000002117338000000000000001UNITMARKS MARKS   31000000000280645000000002117338000000000000001UNIT      SEALNUMBERMAEU12345                                                   SP1                                                                             000000000000000
431000000000280645000000002117338000000000000002UNIT      SEALNUMBERMAEU123456                                                  SP2                                                                             000000000000000
431000000000280645000000002117338000000000000003UNIT      SEALNUMBERMAEU123421                                                  SP3                                                                             000000000000000
431000000000280645000000002117338000000000000004UNIT      SEALNUMBERMAEU123_FIRTS                                               SP1                                                                             000000000000000
431000000000280645000000002117338000000000000005UNIT      SEALNUMBERSEALNUMBER5                                                 SP2                                                                             000000000000000
431000000000280645000000002117338000000000000006UNIT      SEALNUMBERSEALNUMBER6                                                 SP1                                                                             000000000000000
427000000000280645000000001117423000000000000001UNITITEM  ITEMNO                                   000000000000000000001000000000000000003970036
522000000000280645000000001117425000000000000001UNITITEM  QUANTITY  CONTRLPACKCASE      CASE(S)    000000000000000000005000000000000000000000000

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the Cumulative Concatenate pay special attention to its scope parameter. By default its 0 meaning the whole document. In your case i would try a setting of 1 instead as in the image below.

[image]